# jQuery way to find all radio inputs based on style class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the below javascript function to get all the radio buttons on my page and clear them.  The problem is I don't want to clear all of them.  Is there a way to just clear a group of them?  I think the only way I can logically group them (since they're dynamically generated by server side mappings) is to give all the ones I want unchecked a common style class name and search that way.  Any ideas on how to modify the below such that it only finds certain radio buttons who have a certain style class name? align-top is my styleClass name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function clearOtherSelections(selRow){
           var radios = jQuery('td > input[type=radio]');
           radios.attr('checked', false);
           selRow.checked = 'checked';                   
       }
</script>
```

When I used the revised code below, `var radios = jQuery('.align-top');` alerts that all the radios are unchecked which is untrue.  When I use my old way `var radios = jQuery('td > input[type=radio]');` it shows one radio checked an the others not, which is correct.  Why doesn't `jQuery('.align-top');` show an accurate state of the radio checked poperty?

**revised code:**

```
function clearOtherSelections(selRow){
                        //var radios = jQuery('td > input[type=radio]');
                        var radios = jQuery('.align-top');                        
                        for( i = 0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {
                            if( radios[i].checked ) {
                                alert('checked')
                                radios.attr('checked', false);
                            }else{
                                alert('unchecked')
                            }
                        }

                        selRow.checked = 'checked';                    
                    }
```

Comment: `jQuery('.theclassname')` should do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function clearOtherSelections(selRow){
    var radios = jQuery('td > input.specificClassName:radio');
    radios.prop('checked', false);
    selRow.checked = 'checked';                   
}
```

You're setting the `checked` *property*, rather than the *attribute*, so use the `prop()` method, rather than `attr()`.

If the class will only be applied to the specific `input` elements you want to style, you might be able to use, simply:

```
var radios = jQuery('.specificClassName');
```

or:

```
var radios = jQuery('input.specificClassName');
```

References:

- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`:radio` selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/).

Comment: so the :radio is the style class name?

Comment: No, `:radio` is a pseudo-selector, equivalent to `[type='radio']`. `specificClassName` is the style class.

Comment: The `specificClassName` is the string representing the class-name of the element(s), `:radio` (as the link should explain) is, as Zachary notes, a jQuery selector to select input elements of `type="radio"`.

Comment: `+1` and just to let you know `:radio` is on the deprecated list according to [#9400](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:swUc0pVoxzYJ:bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9400+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) (Google Cache link - real site not working for me). It still works for now though. Should also prefer `$('[type=radio]')` since it is quicker in modern browsers - so says the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)

Comment: Good call on `.prop` by the way!

Comment: @andyb: true, that's because it's passed off to `document.querySelectorAll()` (in compatible browsers). I tend to use `:radio` more as a convenience, than for any performance issues (I'm a lazy typist) :)

Comment: I can't get any of these ideas to work, please see my revised code, any ideas?  thanks for the help.

Comment: @c12: if it's still not working, please consider reproducing your set up with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm using jQuery 1.4.1 so I had to use attr() now it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function clearOtherSelections(selRow){
           var radios = jQuery('td > input[type=radio].someclass');
           radios.prop('checked', false);
           selRow.checked = 'checked';                   
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :radio selector, which comes along with jQuery library, and it is more faster as compare to input[type=radio].

```
$("td > input:radio.yourClass") // Gives you all the radio button which has yourClass
```

> jQuery : [radio selector](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)